# How to enumerate boxes?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
\newcommand\answerboxb{%%
\fbox{\rule{0.3in}{16pt}\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}}}

\newcommand\answerboxw{%%
\fbox{\rule{0.3in}{0pt}\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}}}
.....
\centerline \answerboxb  \answerboxb  \answerboxb \answerboxw \answerboxw \answerboxw \answerboxw  \\ 
\centerline 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I want to enumerate these 7 boxes, but I just can't align them. I tried adding spaces, centering and so on but nothing helped me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcommand\answerboxb{%%
\fbox{\rule{0.3in}{16pt}\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}}}

\newcommand\answerboxw{%%
\fbox{\rule{0.3in}{0pt}\rule[-0.5ex]{0pt}{4ex}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
 \answerboxb & \answerboxb & \answerboxb & \answerboxw & \answerboxw & \answerboxw & \answerboxw  \\ 
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```